# If statement block in else statement block

Tags: php, if-statement

I was coding some project and then i went into some problem about part of code. I was bumping my head around, and then i found out where is the problem. Here are two versions of code, first one works, second dont. Second part of code just activate else block, it basically jumps over **if** block of code and goes to else block who then activate die function. Can someone explain what and where I did wrong?
Thanks a lot!

```
// This version of code works!
// Check for errors
            if(!empty($data['error_blog_title']) && !empty($data['error_blog_body'])){
                // There are errors
                $this->loadView('blog/edit', $data);
            } else{
                // No errors, update post
                $this->blogModel->updatePost($data);
                redirect('/blog/index');
            }
```

VS

```
// This one doesnt
// Check for errors
            if(!empty($data['error_blog_title']) && !empty($data['error_blog_body'])){
                // There are errors
                $this->loadView('blog/edit', $data);
            } else{
                if($this->blogModel->updatePost($data)){
                    // Updated succesfully
                    redirect('blog/index');
                } else{
                    // Update failed
                    die('Something went wrong!');
                }
            }
```

Comment: Then `!empty($data['error_blog_title']) && !empty($data['error_blog_body'])` *and* `$this->blogModel->updatePost($data)` are both false, no? That would result in `die` being called and thus "not working". The important bit to keep in mind is that ***there is no "jumps over"***; the conditions are evaluated, and the program operates under defined rules. If the first code "works", it is because it doesn't care what `updatePost` returns.

Comment: (I de-indented the `redirect` in the first code snippet, as the extra indent is meaningless and visually confusing: it's simply a subsequent statement.)

Comment: Nope, they aint false. When I do the first version of code it works, when I try second, i do everything same as one so no false in both if casses else block activates. I know there are no jumps over, but i just removed second if/else block and everything works. I just want to know what I did wrong.

Comment: Again, if those are the only changes, it "works" because the code is not calling `die`. This is the effect of what is happening: `if (false) { } else { if (false) { } else { die('oops'); } }` - ref. https://repl.it/repls/WoozyDrearySection -- So, again (and finally because you can lead a horse to water but..), the `updatePost` does not return what is expected for use with the conditional.

Comment: (Also, `if (x) { xtrue } else { if (y) { xtrue } else { otherwise } }` can be written as `if (x) { xtrue } else if (y) { ytrue } else { otherwise }`, which may help readability in certain cases.)

Comment: I understand what you are saying. I was experimenting and I found out this. Else block activates die(), but when i go to same page my content is changed. So what does that means? Thanks bro!

Comment: Probably means updatePost($data) always returns false (actually, it probably has no return value, which is equivalent to return false)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the solution. In my updatePost() method I changed something a little bit,

i checked execute() and if its alright return TRUE else FALSE

```
if($stmt->execute()){
    $stmt->close();
    return TRUE;
} else{
    $stmt->close();
    return FALSE;
```

And by putting those lines of code I implemented everything works.

BTW I put those lines of code in my other projects but in this I didnt (i forgot).

Thank you all kind people who helped me. :)